# PHP function call stopping page from loading unless it's refreshed

Tags: php, html

I'm running into a problem when calling a PHP function from my HTML code. My PHP code is mainly connecting to my Java server and requesting information about Twitter accounts. I'm requesting to get their profile picture's URL and their Twitter handle. This information is being displayed on the website.

PHP: (Very top of my .php file that I'm working in)

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] !== true) {
    header('Location: ../account/login.php?loggedin=no');
} else {

}
class Functions {
    public static function getName() {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['twittername'])) {
            include '../client.php';
            $_SESSION['twittername'] = Client::send("gettwittername:-1", null, -1);
        }
        return $_SESSION['twittername'];
    }

    public static function getPFP() {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['twitterpic'])) {
            include '../client.php';
            $_SESSION['twitterpic'] = Client::send("gettwitterpic", null, -1);
        }
        return $_SESSION['twitterpic'];
    }
}
?>
```

HTML: (In the same file as the PHP code above)

```
<div class="logcontainer">
    <div class="profilepic">
        <img src="<?php echo Functions::getPFP(); ?>" style="margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;">
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li class="loggedin"><b><span style="color: #AFAFAF;">CURRENTLY LOGGED IN AS</span>
        <br>
        <span style="color: #5d9dfd; font-size: 14px;"><?php $name = Functions::getName(); echo "<a href='http://twitter.com/" . $name . "' target='_blank'>" . $name . "</a>"; ?></span>
        </b>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When running this code it displays my profile picture fine. The server also logs that it received the "gettwitterpic" command. That's all good, however a few lines down when asking to get the name it seems like the function is never called. I never get anything logged on my server and it stops loading the rest of the page. Whenever I refresh the page it loads the Twitter name perfectly fine, but on the first time loading the page it doesn't. Any ideas on how to make this always work, even on the initial page load? Also I'm sure there's better ways to write some of this code, I'm new to web development. How could I improve this functionality in general? Thank you for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Both functions will include the `client.php` file, that's probably your issue.**

---

**In the first page load:**

The function `getPFP()` will check that `$_SESSION['twitterpic']` is not set, then include the `client.php` file.

Then the function `getName()` will verify that the `$_SESSION['twittername']` is also not set and try to include the `client.php` file, again, which is your issue.

---

**In the second page load:**

The function `getPFP()` will check that `$_SESSION['twitterpic']` is set, and will not try to include the `client.php` file.

Then the function `getName()` will verify that the `$_SESSION['twittername']` is not set and include the `client.php` file, this time without problems because it has been included only once.

---

You'll have to change your logic so the file is only included once.

Comment: Also, you should have seen errors on your code. Do you have error reporting on?

Comment: Not on this page, on index I have "ini_set('display_errors', 1);". Will that affect anything on my current page?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you get a timeout when calling:

`$_SESSION['twittername'] = Client::send("gettwittername:-1", null, -1);`

The next time you call the function the `twittername` has apparently been retrieved and is displayed, but the first time it takes to long to get the result back.

Also: what is the reason to put `:-1` after `getwittername` in this line?

Comment: The server can check the name of any Twitter account, and each server has a Twitter account attached to it already. The -1 is saying "Use your attached Twitter account"